# Device Sync of Mongodb for on premise cluster

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, atlas-device-sync

I'm exploring Mongodb, I am building an app that uses mongodb as database, running community edition in a server. I came across Device sync provided by mongodb in Atlas. I can't see this option available for community or enterprise edition of mongodb and is only present in Atlas. Is my understanding correct?
If so, is there a way to do this for on premise Mongodb clusters?

I have tried going through official mongodb docs and community forums. Couldn't find any solution for on premise clusters. Expecting to know if there is a way for on premise clusters and if even enterprise edition of mongodb doesn't provide this feature.

Answer (score 0):

The `Device Sync` feature is specific to `MongoDB Atlas`. It’s a service that bridges the gap between local storage on your device and your `MongoDB Atlas` backend, keeping data current and accurate. This feature is not available in the community or enterprise editions of `MongoDB`.

[You read more here.](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/sync/)

For `on-premise MongoDB clusters`, MongoDB provides a utility called [mongosync](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/mongosync) as part of the `Cluster-to-Cluster Sync`. This utility creates a connection between MongoDB clusters and can be used between self-managed clusters, `MongoDB Atlas` hosted clusters, or a self-managed cluster and an Atlas hosted cluster. However, it’s important to note that this is not the same as the `Device Sync` feature available in `MongoDB Atlas`.

The `mongosync` utility and `Cluster-to-Cluster Sync` are available for M`ongoDB Community Edition`, but are limited some in cases. This means that these tools might not work with the `Community Edition` of `MongoDB` under certain circumstances. The specifics of these circumstances aren’t detailed, I suggest you to contact a `MongoDB` sales representative for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @joão-gervas ! I was thinking to somehow achieve the same effect as that of Device sync for my community edition server, but it doesn't seem to be very feasible to do that.